# Control individual page rotation in R PDF output

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, knitr, tex

Based on some other threads, I found out how to make some pages portrait and some landscape in R (see code below).

What I cannot seem to find is how to rotate the landscape pages by 90 degrees so they are legible.

Explanation below:

Create a "header.tex" file in your working directory, and save it with this text:

```
\usepackage{lscape}
\newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
\newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
```

Then, run the below code:

````
---
title: "PortraitLandscape"
author: "John"
date: "September 1, 2015"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
---


Portrait
```{r}
summary(cars)
```

\newpage
\blandscape

Landscape
```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```

\elandscape
````

The second page will look like this:

[image: The second page should look like this:]

While still leaving it in landscape, how can I make it rotated, like this?

[image: Rotated Image]

Comment: This might help : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40683/rotate-single-pdf-page-when-viewing

Comment: That does look like it might be helpful, but I'm super new to R, much less tex. Is there any chance you could work that up in an answer format to my particular question? I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\pdfpageattr`. Adapting from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40683/rotate-single-pdf-page-when-viewing) (on tex.SE):

header.tex

```
\usepackage{lscape}

\newcommand{\blandscape}{
  \begin{landscape}
  \pagebreak[4]\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}}
\newcommand{\elandscape}{
  \end{landscape}
  \pagebreak[4]\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 0}}
```